# Prisma client: type of table

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typescript-typings, prisma

I'm building an application with `nestjs` and wanna inject only a part of prisma api. So what's the type of the prisma.table (`prisma.tag`) that I'm injecting?

```
export class TagService {
    private readonly tagApi; // what's the correct type of `tagApi`
    private readonly tagApi: Prisma.TagDelegate<Prisma.RejectOnNotFound | Prisma.RejectPerOperation>; // type that is inferred by vscode


    constructor(prisma: PrismaService) {
        this.tagApi = prisma.tag;
    }

    exampleUsageMethod(tagId: string) {
        return this.tagApi.findMany({ where: { id: tagId } });
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't you answer the question yourself in line 3?

Comment: @some-user it looks weird, that's why i'm asking

Comment: Are you getting any type errors due to this defined tagApi type?

Comment: @NurulSundarani no. it's absolutely valid type, just looks weird.